# How to add a check box to every element in an unordered list?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a function that adds a check box to every li element of an unordered list. I am able to accomplish this for one li element:

```
function deleteItems() {
    var list = document.getElementById('grocery-list').getElementsByTagName('li');

    // create checkbox
    delete_box = document.createElement("input");
    delete_box.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

    // this only appends check box to SECOND li
    list[0].append(delete_box);
    list[1].append(delete_box);

    // loop is supposed to add check box to every li element, but only appends LAST li
    // for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
    //     list[i].append(delete_box);
    // }
}
```

The problem is that the check box only appends to one li when the function is called. I'm new to javascript and html and I'm sorry if this type of question has been asked, but I can't find any information on why the list is behaving quite like this.

Thanks

Comment: because you append the same element on every iteration. Since one element can only be in one location, it moves. Clone would make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an element once and try to append it everywhere. Instead, you should create a new element before each addition.

Compare two snippets, please:

```js
const items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

const paragraph = document.createElement("p"); // You created a new element (one time)
paragraph.innerText = "I'm new element";

for (const item of items) {
  item.append(paragraph);
}

// First you add the paragrap to first item
// Then you move the paragraph from first item to second item
// At end you move the paragraph from second item to third item
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

And

```js
const items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (const item of items) {
  const paragraph = document.createElement("p"); // You created a new element
  paragraph.innerText = "I'm new element";

  item.append(paragraph); // And append it to current item
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```js
function deleteItems() {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll('#grocery-list li');

  list.forEach(e => {
    let delete_box = document.createElement("input");
    delete_box.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    e.prepend(delete_box);
  });
}

deleteItems();

document.querySelector('#grocery-list').style["list-style-type"] = "none";
```

```css
#grocery-list li input {
  margin-right: 1em
}
```

```html
<ul id="grocery-list">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

The last line

```
document.querySelector('#grocery-list').style["list-style-type"] = "none";
```

is optional.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="grocery-list">
      <ul id="readroot">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
      function deleteItems() {
        var tableFields = document.getElementById("readroot");
        tableFields = tableFields.children;
        console.log("table fields", tableFields)

        for (let i = 0; i < tableFields.length; i++) {
          delete_box = document.createElement("input");
          delete_box.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
          tableFields[i].append(delete_box);
        }

      }
      deleteItems();

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple clone will make your code work so you are not appending the same element over and over,.

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

var inp = document.createElement('input')
inp.type = 'checkbox'

lis.forEach( function (li) {
  console.log(li)
  li.appendChild(inp.cloneNode())
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```